# Want to find the positions of 1 or 0 occurring in a binary codeword

Tags: c++, xcode, list, vector, binary

I have made a program in which I retain a string that is random binary codeword (1001101 for example) and I want to be able to create a list or vector in which it tells me the positions of the 1s or 0s. For example, the list of positions of 1s would be {1,4,5,7}. And I would also like to find out how to do the reverse. For example, the list of positions of 0s could be {6,3,2}. I don't have a code to show because I really cannot figure this out. And I couldnt find anything on here that exactly helped me. Thank you!

Comment: The binary codewords in a string form? Or integer form?

Comment: the binary codewords are in string form

Comment: Use a for loop or while loop to go over the string, and take to vectors, one to store the indexes of 1's and the other to store the indexes of 0's

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this might help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    string binary_string;
    cin >> binary_string;
    vector <int> position_of_ones,position_of_zeroes;
    for(int i = 0; i < binary_string.length(); i++){
        if(binary_string[i] == '0'){
            position_of_zeroes.push_back(i+1);
        }
        else{
            position_of_ones.push_back(i+1);
        }
    }

    cout << "Position of 0s" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < position_of_zeroes.size(); i++){
        if(i != 0)    cout << ",";
        cout << position_of_zeroes[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Position of 1s" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < position_of_ones.size(); i++){
        if(i != 0)    cout << ",";
        cout << position_of_ones[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
 }
```

And now you can use those vectors.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how do you get the vectors to then print out? Because I am putting your code into my program but getting no output. Thanks!

Comment: There. I updated it. Now the code prints the output too

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
You can visited this link for learning vectors

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test if a specific bit is set by using binary and `&`.

For example, to test if bit 3 is set in `foo` you can do

```
bool is_set = foo & 0b100;
```

Then `is_set` will be `true` if the third bit is set or `false` otherwise.

Wrapping that in a function where you can pass in an integer and the bit number you are interested in and get a bool back saying if it is set or not is trivial.

Using such a function it should be easy to build your lists of all set and all unset bits.

If your codeword is a string you can either a) convert it to integer first then do as outlined above or b) just iterate the string and test each character against '0' or '1' and based on the result add the current position to the right set.

Comment: According to the OP, the binary code word is a string of ones and zeros.

Comment: @ForceBru answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: [Link](http://thispointer.com/find-all-occurrences-of-a-sub-string-in-a-string-c-both-case-sensitive-insensitive/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

/*
 *Find all positions of the a SubString in given String
 */
void findAllOccurances(std::vector<size_t> & vec, std::string data, std::string toSearch)
{
    // Get the first occurrence
    size_t pos = data.find(toSearch);

    // Repeat till end is reached
    while( pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Add position to the vector
        vec.push_back(pos+1); //Added 1, we start to count positions at 1 instead of 0

        // Get the next occurrence from the current position
        pos =data.find(toSearch, pos + toSearch.size());
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string data = "1001101";

    std::vector<size_t> vec;

    // Get All occurrences of the '1' in the vector 'vec'
    findAllOccurances(vec, data , "1");

    std::cout<<"All Index Position of '1' in given string are,"<<std::endl;

    for(size_t pos : vec)
        std::cout<<pos<<std::endl;

    std::vector<size_t> vec0;
    // Get All occurrences of the '0' in the vector 'vec0' backwards
    findAllOccurances(vec0, data , "0");

    std::cout<<"All Index Position of '0' in given string backwards are,"<<std::endl;

    std::reverse_copy(vec0.begin(), vec0.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

[Live sample!](http://ideone.com/BwqIUd)

Output:

> All Index Position of '1' in given string are, 
>  1 
>  4 
>  5
>   
>  7 
>  All Index Position of '0' in given string backwards are,
>   
>  6 
>  3 
>  2